# Android N nothing happens, when I click shortcut of Settings on launcher

Tags: android, settings

By log, I found the action of intent is `"com.andoird.settings/.FallBackHome"` rather than `"com.android.settings/.Settings"`. Can you leave a comment and let me know what your thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a more clear description of your problem.

Comment: First,I want to say thanks.When I click the icon of Settings in the mobile home screen,the App of Settings is not runing 。When I see the log,I can find the Activity,which is com.andoird.settings/.FallBackHome has been started rather than the activity of com.android.settings/.Settings.The more log is  "User unlocked and real home found; let's go!"And FallBackHome.java is found in src/com/android/settings/FallbackHome.java on Android N.